# Can I make my Mac re-adjust to the original brightness when I plug my power cord back in?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, battery, screen, power

When I unplug the power cord from my mac, the brightness dims to save power. When I plug the cord back in, it stays dim rather than going back to the original brightness level. Can I change it so that it will go back to some default brightness for when the power cord is plugged in?

Answer (score 1):

I use a program named [EventScripts](https://www.mousedown.net/software/EventScripts.html) which among the *events* it monitors, there are some **Power Events**, one of which is the **Power switched to mains** *event*. It uses **AppleScript** *scripts* to preform the *action(s)* you want to have happen when a given *event* is triggered.

---

It is a paid app, $3.99 USD, but does have a demo version you can download to test with before purchasing.

- [Mac App Store Preview (US)](https://apps.apple.com/app/eventscripts/id525319418?mt=12)
- [Download for Demo](https://www.mousedown.net/software/Downloads.html)

---

<sup>Note: Other then being a paid user of this app, I have no affiliation with its developer.</sup>